# how to restore using restore class of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo namespace

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
public void  RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath, 
            String serverName, String userName, String password, String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
{
    Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();
    BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
    sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
    sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;
    ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
    Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath;
    String logFileLocation = logFilePath; 
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
    sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName + "_log", logFileLocation));
    sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    sqlRestore.Complete +=new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
    sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    db.SetOnline();
    sqlServer.Refresh();
}
```

On calling this method the restore operation failed with this message

> Restore failed for Server
>   'MDM04\SQLEXPRESS'.

mdm04 is my computer name

the inner exception is

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:
>   Logical file 'vrv' is not part of
>   database 'vrv'. Use RESTORE
>   FILELISTONLY to list the logical file
>   names."

vrv is database name

What should I do to restore the file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Problem is here

```
sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName + "_log", logFileLocation));
```

here databaseName means, name of the database specified in db backup file. But you are specifying the destination db name.

Change it to original db name

here the sample code to read db names from backup file

```
DataTable dtFileList = sqlRestore.ReadFileList(serverName);
string dbLogicalName = dtFileList.Rows[0][0].ToString();
string dbPhysicalName = dtFileList.Rows[0][1].ToString();
string logLogicalName = dtFileList.Rows[1][0].ToString();
string logPhysicalName = dtFileList.Rows[1][1].ToString
```

Comment: You are awesome thank you. I have battled and googled all day and this is the first time someone specified the true meaning of databasename. - So the follow-up question: How do I change the Logical Name after the restore happens?

Answer (score 0):

Now Go to "Browse" Tab and browse the following path-

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
OR
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

Now Select the following dlls

Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

```
         public void  RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath, 
        String serverName, String userName, String password, 
        String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
        {
            Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();
            BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
            sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
            sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;
            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
            Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath;
            String logFileLocation = logFilePath; 
            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName + "_log", logFileLocation));
            sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            sqlRestore.Complete +=new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
            sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            db.SetOnline();
            sqlServer.Refresh();
      }
```